# Detecting (and locating) rogue PXE server on a local area network

Tags: network

The computers on our office building are (via BIOS) configured to **boot PXE** as first option.
This is a useful setting, as long as, when needed, we can remotely restore non-booting machines and all that stuff.

But, if someone sets up a rogue PXE server, machines could be compromised at next reboot (i.e: automatic Windows reboots), so being able to detect such server is a must.

What methods could I use to test if there is any **PXE Server running** on my local network?
If possible, obtaining **some info** (like IP or MAC) to locate this rogue server could be fine.

**Assumptions:**

- The network **already has a DHCP server** running. PXE and DHCP server are not on the same device/computer.

Comment: Isn't PXE information handed out by the DHCP server? So maybe the question should be how to detect rogue DHCP servers

Comment: DHCP server is already on the network, @multithr3at3d . Added info to original question to clarify.

Comment: Your PXE setup depends on DHCP, and thus what you are really looking for is rogue DHCP (or BOOTP) servers. The rest of PXE is TFTP, but that only starts after DHCP has provided TFTP setup data to the system that tries to PXE boot. In normal setups: no DHCP==no PXE. PXE in itself is not a protocol or server, but rather a standard workflow.

Comment: Note, @JohnKeates , the Serva PXE Server for Windows at https://www.vercot.com/~serva/ : it has the option to enable (or not) its own DHCP Server (if there is already another DHCP Server running). Of course you need some DHCP server somewhere, but you could have a rogue PXE server (like Serva) that does not run (feature) a rogue DHCP server.

Comment: To note: "Serva's proxyDHCP only answers to DHCP requests when comming from PXE booting clients, it remains silent otherwise" . Extracted from https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html . So trying to detect a rogue DHCP server would not be enough.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PXE server, PXE is DHCP plus TFTP. And without DHCP a client PC cannot connect to the rogue TFTP server because it doesn’t know where it is.

Answer (score 2):

If PXE (TFTP) server information is provided to the clients via DHCP options, then you may need to prevent that someone could set up a rogue DHCP server in the network to provide the clients with the adress of a malicious TFTP server. [DHCP snooping](https://packetpushers.net/five-things-to-know-about-dhcp-snooping/) may help you: it will allow DHCP reply messages (such as DHCPoffer) only in ports that have been configured as trusted by the network administrator. These trusted ports should be the ports where legitimate DHCP servers are connected to the network o where DHCP replies coming from the legitimate DHCP server are expected.

Besides effectively preventing rogue DHCP servers to work in your network it will also allow you to detect such servers and where they are connected if you monitor the log messages generated when DHCP snooping violations occur

Comment: A possible method, indeed. Thanks you. But as long as DHCP server could be independent from PXE server, I would rather prefer some DHCP-independent way. Added to the original question in order to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap  for this;
read my answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/993783/how-can-i-check-my-pxe-server-configuration/

Gathering the different answers and filtering by e.g. MAC address, you can easily pinpoint the presence of a rogue PXE server.

It should be considered that PXE information (NBP and TFTP server IP) can be located either at the body of the DHCPOFFER packet (`file` and `next-server` fields) or as the corresponding DHCP options.